# Trying to produce a analog clock with moving hands, code does'nt seems to work

Tags: javascript, html

My Code:

```
<html>

<body>
<canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400"
style="background-color: light-orange"></canvas>

<script>
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
var radius = canvas.height / 2;
radius = radius * 0.90
drawClock(); 

function drawClock() {
    drawFace(ctx, radius);
    drawNumbers(ctx, radius);
    drawTime(ctx, radius);
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius){
    var grad;
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
    ctx.fil();
    grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*1.05);
    grad.addColorStop(0, '#333');
    grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white');
    grad.addColorStop(1, '#333');
    ctx.strokeStyle = grad;
    ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1;
    ctz.stroke();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#333';
    ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius){
    var ang;
    var num;
    ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial";
    ctx.textBaseline="middle";
    ctx.textAlign="center";
    for(num = 1;num < 13; num++){
        ang = num * Math.PI / 6;
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
        ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0);
        ctx.rotate(ang);
        ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85);
        ctx.rotate(-ang);
    }
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minute =now.getMinutes();
    var second =now.getSeconds();
    //hour
    hour=hour%12;
    hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+
    (minute*Math.PI/(6*60));
    (second*Math.PI/(360*60));
    drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);

    //mimute
    minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
    drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);

    `[]`//second
    second=(second*Math.PI/30);
    drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width){
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.lineWidth = width;
    ctx.lineCap = "round";
    ctx.moveTo(0,0);
    ctx.rotate(pos);
    ctx.lineTo(0, -lenght);
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.rotate(-pos);
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I followed course instructions and produced the code listed above. However, it does'nt produce the expected result, Clock with moving hands.

Comment: It probably doesn't work because of all the "your text" everywhere. ;)

Comment: Please explain by what you mean, "your text everywhere".

Comment: ©Khal Your whole post was a mess before DreamBold edited it. Click on "edited" above next to your user name, and you will see how it looked like.

Comment: Hi Rickard, The "Mess" as you pointed out was not my coding.It was Stackoverflow systemasking me tp leave 4 indents to my code => a mess

Comment: I am new to coding and my tutor sent me the code. However, it did not produce the results. His coding showed the clock working, yet mine did'nt.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem was a dozen or so misspelled words.

**Canvas Position:** I added a `translate` call before and after drawing the clock to move it away from the top left corner.

**Interval:** I added an interval so your clock updates once per second.

```js
 var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas"); 
 var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d"); 
 var radius = canvas.height / 2; 
 radius = radius * 0.90; 
 drawClock();
 setInterval(drawClock, 1000)

function drawClock() { 
  ctx.translate(200, 200)
  drawFace(ctx, radius); 
  drawNumbers(ctx, radius); 
  drawTime(ctx, radius); 
  ctx.translate(-200, -200)
}

function drawFace(ctx, radius){ 
  var grad; 
  ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius, 0, 2*Math.PI); 
  ctx.fillStyle = 'white'; 
  ctx.fill(); 
  grad = ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*1.05,0,0,radius*2); 
  grad.addColorStop(0, '#333'); 
  grad.addColorStop(0.5, 'white'); 
  grad.addColorStop(1, '#333'); 
  ctx.strokeStyle = grad; 
  ctx.lineWidth = radius*0.1; 
  ctx.stroke(); 
  ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.arc(0, 0, radius*0.1, 0, 2*Math.PI); 
  ctx.fillStyle = '#333'; 
  ctx.fill();
}

function drawNumbers(ctx, radius){ 
  var ang; 
  var num; 
  ctx.font = radius*0.15 + "px arial"; 
  ctx.textBaseline="middle"; 
  ctx.textAlign="center"; 
  for(num = 1;num < 13; num++){ 
    ang = num * Math.PI / 6; 
    ctx.rotate(ang); 
    ctx.translate(0, -radius*0.85); 
    ctx.rotate(-ang); 
    ctx.fillText(num.toString(), 0, 0); 
    ctx.rotate(ang); 
    ctx.translate(0, radius*0.85); 
    ctx.rotate(-ang); 
  } 
}

function drawTime(ctx, radius){ 
  var now = new Date(); 
  var hour = now.getHours(); 
  var minute =now.getMinutes(); 
  var second =now.getSeconds(); 
  //hour 
  hour=hour%12; 
  hour=(hour*Math.PI/6)+ (minute*Math.PI/(6*60))+ (second*Math.PI/(36060)); 
  drawHand(ctx, hour, radius*0.5, radius*0.07);

  //mimute
  minute=(minute*Math.PI/30)+(second*Math.PI/(30*60));
  drawHand(ctx, minute, radius*0.8, radius*0.07);

  //second
  second=(second*Math.PI/30);
  drawHand(ctx, second, radius*0.9, radius*0.02);
}

function drawHand(ctx, pos, length, width){ 
  ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.lineWidth = width; 
  ctx.lineCap = "round"; 
  ctx.moveTo(0,0); 
  ctx.rotate(pos); 
  ctx.lineTo(0, -length); 
  ctx.stroke(); 
  ctx.rotate(-pos); 
}
```

```html
 <canvas id="canvas" width="400" height="400" style="background-color: light-orange;">
```

Comment: Hi Richard. Firstly, thank you for taking the time to help with this problem. Greatly appreciated. As Rickard, pointed out that my coding "was a mess". I wanted to clarify this point, as I said to him, that it was Stackoverflow's system requesting that I must make 4 indents to each coding line inorder to submit my question. Secondly, I am new to coding and have some way to go before perfecting.  Thirdly, I tried to make changes to my code as shown.

Comment: However, this did'nt produce the results - only  a square orange back-face.  I ran the Code Snippet and it does show the clock working, and yet mine does not. In desperation, I even copied and pasted your amended code on my Sublime Text editor  and came out white screen with text.   I don't know where the problem is.  Please kindly advise

Comment: Here's a code sandbox I made. Maybe that will help? https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-david-koeg15?file=/index.js

Comment: I think the only other non-spelling change I made to the code was changing your radial gradient to have the correct number of parameters: `ctx.createRadialGradient(0,0,radius*1.05,0,0,radius*2);`

Comment: If your program is throwing errors, have you tried opening the developer console to see what the errors are? That would help diagnose your problem if these other ideas don't work.

Comment: @Khal In case you're having a problem because you need all of your code to be in a single file, I changed the code sandbox to do that (you can ignore the package.json. It won't let me delete it).

Comment: I just went through my code and found couple of mistakes: 1. Corrected the Number of parameters (the radius parameter for radius was 2.05 instead of 1.05.  And I did'nt add the closing Script tag. As you can see I still have a lot to learn :)   The corrected code DOES produce the clock with moving hnds. Again, thanks for you advise and help.